# Can I mount a Rails engine twice with different namespace in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to use my engine's routes with namespaces.
My application's routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin, admin_scope: true do
    mount Notifications::Engine, at: '/notifications'
  end
  namespace :user, user_scope: true do
    mount Notifications::Engine, at: '/notifications'
  end
end
```

My engine's routes.rb file:

```
Notifications::Engine.routes.draw do
  get 'messages' => 'messages#index', as: 'messages'
end
```

I tought

```
user_notifications.messages_path
```

will print /user/notifications/message and

```
admin_notifications.messages_path
```

will print /admin/notifications/messages. But

```
admin_notifications.messages_path
```

gives me the same /user/notifications/messages path.

Why?
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you're looking for:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin, admin_scope: true do
    mount Notifications::Engine => '/notifications', as: 'admin_notifications'
  end
  namespace :user, user_scope: true do
    mount Notifications::Engine => '/notifications', as: 'user_notifications'
  end
end
```

Comment: But the second mount overwrites the first again. admin_admin_notifications.messages_path and user_user_notifications.messages_path both gives /user/notifications/messages.